# Finding the value t for which two vectors are parallel to each other

Tags: vector-spaces

How would I go about finding for which t value $u - w + v({1 \over 3} - t)$ is parallel  to $u$?

Comment: Where does $\,t\,$ play any role in your question?...

Comment: Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: Are $\,u,v,w\,$ the usual unitary pairwise perpendicular vectors, say in space $\,\Bbb R^3\,$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\alpha =u-w+v(\frac13 -t)$ and $u$ are nonzero, set $\alpha=\lambda u$, and then solve for $t$.

(We may consider the zero vector to be parallel to every vector.)

Comment: Minor detail: if $u=0$, don't we say that $u$ is parallel to any vector? In this case, your equation has no solution whenever $-w+v(1/3-t)$. But you probably took $(u,v,w)$ to be canonical basis like DonAntonio anyway, in which case my comnment does not apply.

Comment: I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the vectors $\,u,v,w\,$ are the usual unitary pairwise orthogonal ones, we can write

$$u=(1,0,0)\;,\;v=(0,1,0)\;,\;w=(0,0,1)\Longrightarrow u-w+\left(\frac{1}{3}-t\right)v=\left(1\,,\,\frac{1}{3}-t\,,\,-1\right)$$

Thus the given vectors are parallel iff

$$0=\left|u\times \left(u-w+\left(\frac{1}{3}-t\right)v\right)\right|=\begin{vmatrix}\vec x&\vec y&\vec z\\{}\\1&0&0\\{}\\1&\frac{1}{3}-t&-1\end{vmatrix}=\left(0\;,\;1\;,\;\frac{1}{3}-t\right)$$

So, as you can see, for no value of $\,t\,$ we get the zero vector and thus the given vectors are never parallel.

If you didn't mean the usual $\,u,v,w\,$ then you must say what you meant